# Calculate Scope for a client by avoiding multiple entries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a scenario where role and client is being stored in a table and we have to fetch it in a Dictionary and have to ensure that for a user no client have more than one role entry and in case it have take the latest RowVersion Record.

Inside table we have unique constraint on user, role and clientid and data something like below:

```
#1- User,Role, Client Id, TimeStamp, rowVersion
    201,READ,101, 1/18/2019, 2
    201,WRITE,101, 1/18/2019, 1
    201,ADMIN,102, 1/18/2019, 3
    202,READ,102, 1/19/2019, 12
```

For a User 201 - Client 101 can have only one role in case have multi roles - pick latest version after sorting. 
In #1 above it will calculate to below and stored in Dictionary -

```
201,READ,101, 1/18/2019, 2
201,ADMIN,102, 1/18/2019, 3
```

How can i achieve this efficiently using LINQ while query that data and store in Dictionary ?

**EDIT**
Actually RowVersion is SQL Server row version like this 0x0000000000019E12 just to simplify i added numeric to show.

We need to keep in mind that for a given user we are calculating for this RoleScope. Means for user 201 in my example result would be

```
201,READ,101, 1/18/2019, 2
201,ADMIN,102, 1/18/2019, 3
```

Answer in SQL form which i want to transform in LINQ

```
select * from(
select UserId,ClientId,RowVersion,RoleCode,row_number() 
over(partition by ClientId order by RowVersion desc) as roworder
from dbo.UR where UserId=6
) temp
where roworder=1
```

Comment: Did you try any Linq qyery?

Comment: I tried only SQL one which I updated in above Question

Comment: Here is fiddle of working Solution = https://dotnetfiddle.net/ftQYij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand what you are wanting. And assuming rowversion is just an `int` (and not a SqlServer `timeStamp`)

1. use `GroupBy`
2. `OrderBy` rowVersion
3. Select `Last` (highest)
4. `ToDictionary`

Example

```
var results = list.GroupBy(x => x.ClientId)
                  .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.rowVersion).Last())
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.ClientId);
```

Comment: So basically I want to Order by ClientId and then Row Version and then pick top for each Role of that User 201 for example.
201,READ,101, 1/18/2019, 2
201,ADMIN,102, 1/18/2019, 3

Comment: i made a small change to choose First instead of Last as want latest one,

Answer (score 1):

Having the following class:

```
class ClientRole
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public int RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Try this:

```
var clientRoles = new List<ClientRole>
{
    new ClientRole { ClientId = 101, Role = "READ", RowVersion = 2 },
    new ClientRole { ClientId = 101, Role = "WRITE", RowVersion = 1 },
    new ClientRole { ClientId = 102, Role = "ADMIN", RowVersion = 2 },
    new ClientRole { ClientId = 102, Role = "OTHER", RowVersion = 12 }
};

var clientRolesDic = (
    from cr in clientRoles
    group cr by cr.ClientId into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(i => i.RowVersion).First()
    )
    .ToDictionary(k => k.ClientId);
```

Comment: it is missing UserId part as for a given user we need to return his RoleXClientId mapping. 201 user have  

201,READ,101, 1/18/2019, 2
201,ADMIN,102, 1/18/2019, 3

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an easy query:

```
var clientRoles = new []
{
    new { ClientId = 101, Role = "READ", RowVersion = 2 },
    new { ClientId = 101, Role = "WRITE", RowVersion = 1 },
    new { ClientId = 102, Role = "ADMIN", RowVersion = 3 },
    new { ClientId = 102, Role = "READ", RowVersion = 2 },
};

var result =
    from cr in clientRoles
    orderby cr.ClientId, cr.RowVersion descending
    group cr by cr.ClientId into gs
    from g in gs.Take(1)
    select g;
```

This returns just these rows:

```
    new { ClientId = 101, Role = "READ", RowVersion = 2 },
    new { ClientId = 102, Role = "ADMIN", RowVersion = 3 },
```

It appears that you had an error in your source data - the last row should have had a `RowVersion` of `2`, not `12`.

Comment: thank you let me try this, there is no error in data actually it is SQL Row version like 0x0000000000019E12

Comment: @DevG - No worries, but the error is in your sample data in the question otherwise you wouldn't get your sample output - the row with 12 would instead be returned.

Comment: If you see that four rows have two users  201 and 202. If i am querying for user 201 in that case his RoleScope will be 

201,READ,101, 1/18/2019, 2
201,ADMIN,102, 1/18/2019, 3

in your data you forgot User part. Or may be I am failed to specify it correctly?

Comment: added clear details in the question, sorry about that in case that confused you.

Answer (score 0):

In case Fiddle Stop working here is the FULL working solution including suggested by Randall above.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Simple {
  public static void Main() {
            var userRoles = (new[] 
            { 
            new { clientid=1 , rowVersion = 1 , role="READ" },
            new { clientid=1 , rowVersion = 2 , role="EDIT" },
            new { clientid=2 , rowVersion = 3 , role="ADMIN" },
            new { clientid=1 , rowVersion = 4 , role="VIEW" }
        });

var o = userRoles.OrderByDescending(x => x.rowVersion)
                .GroupBy(x => x.clientid)
                .SelectMany(g =>
                   g.Select((j, i) => new { j.rowVersion, j.role, rn = i + 1 })
                   );

    var z =  o.Select(x => new {x.rowVersion, x.role, x.rn}).Where(a => a.rn==1);

      var results = userRoles.GroupBy(x => x.clientid)
                  .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.rowVersion).First());

          Console.WriteLine("Solution #1");

        foreach (var i in z)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i.rowVersion, i.role, i.rn);
        }

      Console.WriteLine("Solution #2");

      foreach (var k in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", k.rowVersion, k.role);
        }

  }
  }
```

Comment: Only issue i face with this when i ported it inside code is around "Exception message: Failed to compare two elements in the array"